# Single query slower than 3 queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using .NET framework 4.5.1 Linq to SQL.

I have this product class using code first:

```
public class Part
{
    public int PartID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "xxx")]        
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Index(IsClustered = false, IsUnique = false,Order =1)]
    public string Part_Number { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Index(IsClustered = false, IsUnique = false, Order = 2)]
    public string Manufacturer_Number { get; set; }
}
```

I have approximately 2500000 of those entities in the database.

**First approach**

```
var query = db.Parts.Where(s => s.Manufacturer_Number == sstring).ToList();                
query.AddRange(db.Parts.Where(s => s.Part_Number == sstring).ToList());
query.AddRange(db.Parts.Where(s => s.Title == sstring).ToList());
```

**Second approach**

```
var query = db.Parts.Where(s => s.Manufacturer_Number == sstring
|| s.Part_Number == sstring || s.Title == sstring).ToList();
```

The first approach is 100 times faster than the second approach. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You should look at SQL that prodused by your linq and then check execution plan in your ManagmentStudio. Could be that you have indexes on each field and simple queries can use them but not your last one.

Comment: I hope he has indexes if you have 2,5M records in a table...

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve..?

Comment: According to @JordyvanEijk comment. Can you show us the query execution plan from Sql Server please ?

Comment: `Title` isn't indexed so searching on it will always result in a table scan. I'd bet that the third query's  timing wasn't included in the first approach, or Linq to SQL generates very bad SQL when faced with OR.

Comment: Is `sstring` NULL? This is the only case I can think of where the third query wouldn't result in a full table scan, since Title is `Required` (NOT NULL). Although the optimizer could be smart enough to eliminate `Title` from the search criteria if `sstring` was NULL

Comment: Votin to close. YOu pprovide no sensible information - no index list, no query plan, no SQL. Linq2SQL being a SQL generator and this being a speed query the LINQ part is irrelevant - post the generated SQL and all SQL Server level inforamtion (assumed and actual query plan, table definitions with all indices).

Comment: @DirkVollmar we can only guess unless the OP posts the table schema and the query, but by default, an unadorned `string` property generates  an `NVARCHAR(4000)` column. The `Required` attribute would result in `NOT NULL`. Of course, the OP could have created the table by hand.

Comment: Can I ask a dumb question:  Do both queries return the same number of rows ?

Answer (score 1):

First without an index on title I find it a bit hard to believe that you're getting the behaviour you claim.

Set statistics io on at a minimum and add the results to this question.

But that said, the first approach is actually three trips to the database, but will leverage the indexe created.

The second approach is a single trip to the database but will al out certainly result in a full table scan, with 2,500,000 rows is likely to take a non trivial amount of time.

Comment: If all fields are indexed, this won't result in a table scan. The only case I can think of where there *could* be a real difference (ie the OP didn't make a timing error), is if `sstring` is NULL. Title has the `Required` attribute, meaning it is NOT NULL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Are you certain that SQL Server will use multiple indexes in a single query?

Comment: SQL Server will use the most efficient option. Of course it will, if this *is* the cheapest option. Or it may decide to cache temporary results in tempdb. Bad statistics or missing indexes though means that it may pick the wrong plan because it didn't know what kind of data it would find in `Title`. In any case, the two approaches aren't even equivalent - the first approach *will* return multiple times rows that fulfill more than one condition. The second approach will filter the rows against all conditions and return them once

Answer (score 1):

As i say problem could be in indexes if you want your query go faster with this exact query i suggest you to create this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX PartIndex 
ON Part (PartID, Manufacturer_Number, Part_Number, Title)
```

Don't forget to update statistics if you change your table data a lot.

Comment: Part_Number and Manufacturer_Number are already indexed. The properties have the `Index` attribute. It's the `Title` property that doesn't have an index. One would expect both attempts to take about the same time because of that. The OP should post the generated queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agree, let's wait for him

Comment: Helpfully, SQL Server keeps track of which indexes you *don't* have, and which would've made a difference.  Here's some script which'll tell you which indexes you can add, which will give the best performance improvements:  http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/FindingMissingIndexes.htm